# Searching query to get records without duplicate

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I would like to write a SQL query in a SQL Server stored procedure so that the result will not have duplicate rows. I have a table containing the following fields

```
ArticleId, Topic, Introduction, ArticleText, TagsAndKeywords
```

(`TagsAndKeywords` are some info to make search easier)

Suppose the user is giving a search for "Best practices in SQL".

Then the query should do

1. a full text match in `Topic` first, `Introduction, TagsAndKeywords & ArticleText`
2. split the search text (here 4 words) and search it inside `Topic`, `Introduction`, `TagsAndkeywords` and `ArticleText`

I want to get a single table without duplicate rows. Please assist me to solve this

Thanks

Comment: And which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Use "Distinct" [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831.aspx)

```
Select Distinct ArticleId, Topic, Introduction, ArticleText, TagsAndKeywords 
From myTable
Where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

User below mentioned query. Seems ArticleId is PK show including PK in the Select will again produce duplicate results.

Select Distinct Topic, Introduction, ArticleText, TagsAndKeywords 
From myTable
Where ...

Cheers.